# Real time, auto updating, incremental plot in R

Tags: r, plot, real-time

I'm trying to make a dynamic plot, sort of like auto updating, incremental, possibly real time.
I want to accomplish something like this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7qMxpDUS3c

This is what I have done so far. Suppose you have a time series in a data.frame called temp. First column is the time and the second column is where the values are.

```
for(i in 1: length(temp$Time[1:10000]))
{
flush.console()
plot(temp$Time[i:i+100],temp$Open[i:i+100],
xlim=c(as.numeric(temp$Time[i]),as.numeric(temp$Time[i+150])),
ylim=c(min(temp$Open[i:i+100]),max(tmep$Open[i:i+120])))
Sys.sleep(.09)
}
```

This does plot incrementally but I don't get the 100 units long time series instead i get just one point updating.

Comment: is max(tmep$Open a typo? Should be 'temp' shouldn't it? Did you paste this in from your session? It should give you a warning...

Comment: length(temp$Time[1:10000]) is always going to be 10000, even if the vector isn't longer than 10000 (it gets padded with NAs). for(i in 1:10000) should do nicely.

Comment: Spacedman, thanks for replying. The first is a typo. Second should not make any change to the actualy outcome. In fact I tried and it didn't do anything.

Comment: How does temp get updated as data comes in eg. from a file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window)) {
    flush.console()
    plot(df$time,df$y,type='l',xlim=c(i,i+window))
    Sys.sleep(.09)
}
```

Going through your code:

```
# for(i in 1: length(temp$Time[1:10000])) { 
for (i in 1:10000) # The length of a vector of 10000 is always 10000
    flush.console()
    # plot(temp$Time[i:i+100],temp$Open[i:i+100],
    # Don't bother subsetting the x and y variables of your plot.
    # plot() will automatically just plot those in the window.
    plot(temp$Time,temp$Open, 
    xlim=c(as.numeric(temp$Time[i]),as.numeric(temp$Time[i+150]))
    # Why are you setting the y limits dynamically? Shouldn't they be constant?
    # ,ylim=c(min(temp$Open[i:i+100]),max(tmep$Open[i:i+120])))
    Sys.sleep(.09)
}
```

Comment: OMG you are my favorite! I manly love you! this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you guru.
To answer your your last question. Its not constant as they are open prices for say second data?

Comment: @nograpes, this is very useful thank you! I suspect this does not apply to `ggplot`. Do you know of a similar `ggplot2` solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205610/real-time-auto-incrementing-ggplot-in-r