# Real-time auto incrementing ggplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365857/real-time-auto-updating-incremental-plot-in-r) answers how to create incremental plots in R with a real-time effect.

I want to do the same thing with `ggplot2` instead of R's base `plot`. Directly copying from the answer in that link, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window)) {
  print(i)
  flush.console()
  ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y), size=0.7) + xlim(i,i+window)
  Sys.sleep(.09)
}
```

I guess the image rendering for `ggplot2` works differently. Is it possible to create a real-time updating effect with `ggplot2`?

Ideally, I want to be able to display multiple `geom_line`s. But I guess the logic will be the same.

Also, is it possible to achieve this when the plot is "Zoom"ed in in R-Studio?

Comment: Enclose the whole `ggplot(...)+...+...` line in `print(...)`, as in `print(ggplot(df)+...)`

Comment: @jlhoward, thank you. It indeed displays the plots one after another but this results more in a "flashing effect" rather than a visually continuous flow . If I reduce `Sys.sleep` to have a more seamless effect (e.g. with `0.01`), nothing gets plotted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear where you're going with this, but this code will produce an HTML animation that renders smoothly. It will take a while (about a minute) to create the animation though.

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)
# your data
n  <- 1000
df <- data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window <- 100
# create the animation
saveHTML({
for(i in 1:(n-window)) {
  print(ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y), size=0.7) + xlim(i,i+window))
}
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at this to visualise trade strategy testing.

Comment: Stumbled on this today.  Any idea how to control the width/height of the resulting image?

Comment: but it's not real-time