# Real-time auto incrementing ggplot in R with timestamp

Tags: r, ggplot2, real-time

Continuing on this thread :

[Real-time auto incrementing ggplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205610/real-time-auto-incrementing-ggplot-in-r)

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)

# your data
n  <- 200
df <- data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window <- 100

# create the animation
saveHTML({
  for(i in 1:(n-window)) {
    print(ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y), size=0.7) + xlim(i,i+window))
  }
})
```

The above works beautifully

When I generate timestamps with dates and time. It doesn't work anymore. 
The plot is static instead of moving along time on the x-axis.

```
timestamp <- seq(ISOdate(2016, 12, 01), ISOdate(2016, 12, 31), "hour")
df2 <- data.frame(timestamp, y = runif(length(timestamp)))
window <- 100


# create the animation
saveHTML({
  for (i in 1:(length(timestamp)-window)) {
    print(ggplot(df2) + 
            geom_line(aes(timestamp, y), size = 0.20) + 
            ggtitle("Real-time ggplot") +
            xlab("time") + 
            ylab("count"))

  }
})
```

Comment: That code runs fine for me.

Comment: Yes it runs fine, but I'm getting a static plot from start to end date. 
I wanted it to move windows over time like the link I provided at the start of the post.

Comment: Then you'd need to change the data being fed to `ggplot()`. You could use subsets, for example.