# Plotting tweets on real time with R

Tags: r, twitter, plot, twitter-streaming-api

I have tried to smoothly update twitter timeline plots, however I can´t achieve this with twitteR package. I would really appreciate any help on this problem. The plots of the following code doesn´t updates as smoothly as [this one does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365857/real-time-auto-updating-incremental-plot-in-r).

```
library(twitteR)

df <- data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window <- 1 

for(i in 1:10) {
              flush.console()
              ts_plot(data.frame(stream_tweets(q = q, timeout = streamtime)),
                      by = "secs", xlim = c(i,i+window))
              Sys.sleep(.09)
            }
```