# Edit or undo segment or text for real time plot in R

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

Say I want to display a web data stream in real time in a plot in R. Is there a way, to just draw and undraw the most recent text box or segment over the existing plot, rather than drawing the entire plot from scratch each time new data arrives, like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365857/real-time-auto-updating-incremental-plot-in-r)?.

At the core of this question is how to undo, or edit an existing object in a plot (let it be a segment or text box)

Something like this:

```
plot(0) #Create background plot

#draw first line and text
grid.segments(0,  0, 0.5,0.5, name="A")
grid.text("A", x = unit(0.5, "npc"),y = unit(0.5, "npc"),name="TA")

#draw second line and text, but erase prior element first
  #erase prior element
   grid.remove("A")
   grid.remove("TA")
grid.segments(0.5,  0.5, 0,0.5, name="B")
grid.text("B", x = unit(0.5, "npc"),y = unit(0.5, "npc"),name="TB")

#draw new incoming element
  #erase prior element
   grid.remove("B")
   grid.remove("TB")
grid.segments(0.5,  0.5, 0.5,1, name="C")
grid.text("C", x = unit(0.5, "npc"),y = unit(0.5, "npc"),name="TC")
```